# yet another question about headless on Mac OS X

Tags: ssh, headless, macos

- I downloaded: RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE
- wrote a disk image of it on my SD card (using Disk Utility's "restore to" feature).
- added a ssh file in the root of the boot volume
- connected my raspberry pi via ethernet to my Mac Pro desktop
- observed small green light flicker 2-3 times when power up the device (assuming it is booted)
- observe solid yellow & green lights by the pi's ethernet port
- In System Preferences > Sharing, I have activated Internet Sharing with "share your connection from Airpot", and "to computers using: Ethernet 2"

And I see that System Preferences > Networking shows Ethernet 2 with a "yellow light" that says "self-assigned IP" with 169.254.125.225 -- Seems like the problem?

If I try to change this to DHCP with a manual address (my mac pro desktop has the ip of 192.168.1.7) of 192.168.2.7... Then the System Preferences > Networking tab shows Ethernet 2 with a "green light", saying "Ethernet 2 is currently active and has the IP address 192.168.2.7."

So then I see:

```
 >ifconfig | grep "inet "
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet 192.168.3.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.3.255
    inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet 192.168.2.7 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    inet 192.168.1.7 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet 192.168.104.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.104.255
    inet 172.16.162.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.162.255
```

and if I use nmap, I get:

```
>nmap -p 22 192.168.2.255/24
 Starting Nmap 5.50 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-14 18:12 PDT
 Strange error from connect (64):Host is down
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is unclear, but depending on what you want to do there are solutions.

1. If you are attempting to connect to the Pi from your Mac **DO NOT** turn on ICS, just connect the Pi with an Ethernet cable. The Mac can `ssh` into a Pi with a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)
   (169.). You can either connect using the [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) **OR** using [Zero-conf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)
   as `raspberrypi.local` See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for more detail.
2. If you have a keyboard and monitor connected to the Pi and want to use the Mac to share internet access, ICS on the Mac should allocate an IP address. This **WILL NOT** let you access the Pi from the Mac.
3. The best solution is to connect the Pi to your router (using either
   Ethernet or WiFi). This will give the Pi internet access, but also allow access from the Mac.

PS Using `Disk Utility` **MAY** work, but as macOS has no knowledge of `ext4` this is unclear. You would be better to use `dd` (hundreds of tutorials) or `Etcher`

Comment: Thank you!  I think my problem was Disk Utility.  Redoing it with dd seems to have solved all of my problems!